# Vertical direction in images

Tags: image

Mathematica's relatively new **Image** structure and related functions are very useful, but it is a great disappointment that they adopted the convention that the first row is at the top of the image. This means, among many other confusing things, that the column indexes run in a positive cartesian direction, but the row indexes run in a negative cartesian direction. I expect I will have to live with this, but I wondered if there was any global variable that could customize this, sort of like **FourierParameters**?

Answer (score 4):

No, this doesn't exist as far as I know. There is one thing that might help you in certain situations when you work with the pixel data of images: `ImageData` has an option `DataReversed` which you can set to true, if you would like to extract the pixel matrix *upside down* so that the coordinates are correct again.